# Finding the result of a definite integral when its limit is changed and integrand is not symmetrical

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_involving_only_exponential_functions), the an $x^2$ integral with a function of exponential raised to the power of a quadratic is given by:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2 +bx} dx= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}(2a+b^2)}{4a^{5/2}}e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}  \\\text{where   } (Re(a)>0)$$

Now that the physics-related integral that I'd like to solve has the same form but different limits, i.e.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-ax^2 +bx} dx$$ and I couldn't find the evaluated expression of it online. Since the integrand in question, when plotted, is not symmetrical on the y-axis. Which means to solve the integral that I want it won't be just as trivial as computing the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and divide the answer by 2. Given that my constants $a$ and $b$ in this case has the form
$$a = \frac{1}{4(\sigma / a_0)^2}$$
and
$$b = - \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{2t}{k(1-t)}\right)$$
where both expressions are real numbers and $n$ has to be a positive integer, how can one in this case change the result of the first integral to solve my second?

Addendum:
Alternately if I was to complete the square of my integral I'd have it in the form of
$$A\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-(x + c)^2} dx$$
where $A$ is some real number constant. However for an integral of this form I haven't been able to find a standard solution for it either.

TL;DR: I'm a physicist not a mathematician, therefore I need help on solving an integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $x=y+\frac{b}{2a}$, then it reduces to integrals of the type
$$
\int_{-b/(2a)}^\infty y^k e^{-ay^2}dy, \qquad k=0,1,2.
$$
The one with $k=1$ can be computed by substitution. The one with $k=0$ involves the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) $\mathrm{erf}$, the one with $k=2$ can be reduced to it.

End result:
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-ax^2+bx}dx
&= \int_{-b/(2a)}^\infty \left(y+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2e^{-ay^2+\frac{b^2}{4a}}dy \\
&= e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}} \int_{-b/(2a)}^\infty \left(y+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2e^{-ay^2}dy \\
&= \dots \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(2 a+b^2\right) e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}
   \left(\mathrm{erf}\!\left(\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right)+1\right)+2 \sqrt{a} b}{8
   a^{5/2}}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Can I ask how you have arrived to this result?Can I find it online anywhere?

Comment: You can obtain the result easily by asking WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2+Exp%5B-a+x%5E2+%2B+b+x%5D+for+x+from+0+to+infinity+with+a%3E0

Comment: But I suggest you try the steps. In the second line of my computation you can expand $(y+b/(2a))^2$ and then you work out the 3 integrals separately. Yeah I know, it's painful... But you are a physicist :P

Comment: Your substitution actually leads to $\int_{-b/(2a)}^\infty \left(y+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2e^{-ay^2+\frac{by}{2}+\frac{b^2}{4a}}dy$. So I actually don't see how it becomes easier to solve apart from the fact that WolframAlpha just spits out an answer.

Comment: No, the original exponent $-ax^2+bx$ becomes just $-ay^2+b^2/(4a)$, and the second term can be brought outside of the integral.

Comment: Oh I made a silly mistake there! Thank you.